# Unable to save a layout in Xamarin.Android project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I created a Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio 2013.

When I try to edit and then save a layout, I get this strange error: "Connection closed"

[image]

I tried to restart VS - it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had to upgrade the **Android SDK** tools.

Reference: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14344/